Is it possible that the running Docker container does not contain the compiled files of the NodeJS application?
I have a Node.js application that consists of different microservices. Each microservice is a Node.js or NestJS app with .js and .ts files. Every such app has its own Dockerfile in the app's folder. These files usually contain similar lines for the build step:
dockerfile
WORKDIR /app
RUN npm run build && npm prune --production --force && rm -rf src

For example, this code belongs to the 'gateway-server' service. If I launch a terminal shell inside the running container, I can see compiled files (only .js and .js.map files) inside the 'app' folder. This is the case for other services as well.
However, our app has a microservice labeled 'sps'. The Dockerfile for the 'sps' app does not contain any 'build' instructions. When I run a shell inside its container, the 'app' folder consists of the original source files - .ts and .js files (raw source code).
I have a few questions:
How is it possible that the Node.js app container does not contain compiled files? I tried searching for them using catalog search and the find command but found nothing.
Could the compiled files be located in some external volume, or were they built in RAM? If so, how can I find their location - can Docker inspect <containerID> help me?
Why might someone use such a setup without compiled files?

Why is your image building the project? What are the benefits of this pattern?

Each microservice builds only its own source code, not the whole project.

Still, why don't deploy into the image the artifact instead of the source code?

Maybe this is an option in normal situation but my task is to replace 2 files inside working container and this how it did before in another containers with compiled filed inside 'app' folder.

Do you have a [mcve], in particular showing how you're running the container and showing what files are or aren't present?  For Node applications in particular it seems to be a common practice to use a bind mount to require the source to be present on the source machine instead of having everything encapsulated in the image; you may need to remove volume mounts depending on your setup.  docker inspect is unlikely to be useful.

If there is something like ts-node, you won't see any compiled files 'cause it compiles + runs them on the fly without emitting to disk. Check out the package.json to see how the app is started.

Yes, you are right. Everything is working 'on the fly' with 'ts-node'.
